# Do thread safe value types already exist somewhere in the standard library?

Tags: c++

I needed a few thread safe ints and floats, I figured I'd build a template class for them, started out like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct MutexValue {
    T Value;
    std::mutex Mutex;
    MutexValue(T Value) { this->Value = Value; }

    MutexValue& operator=(const MutexValue &rhs) {
        Mutex.lock();
        Value = rhs.Value;
        Mutex.unlock();
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And then I was going to write all the other operators for it (assuming T is a simple numeric datatype) but then it occurred to me that this kind of thing should be fairly common and might already exist somewhere in std. So, should I continue with my class or would I be rebuilding the bicycle?

Comment: This isn't thread safe. The read from `rhs` can race with a concurrent write.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::atomic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe, you are looking for the family of [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) types.